# Date conversion in R not registering string correctly

Tags: r

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work:

```
as.Date("01/08/15", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "0015-01-08"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use lower-case `%y`. Upper-case `%Y` requires a 4-digit year. (In my opinion, the entire command should have failed with an error message, but unfortunately it didn't.) See [`strptime()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html), which documents the format codes.

Comment: zomg, I can't upvote that enough. If you put that as answer, I'll give you the credit. Serves me right for coding late at night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use lower-case `%y`. Upper-case `%Y` requires a 4-digit year. (In my opinion, the entire command should have failed with an error message, but unfortunately it didn't.) See [`strptime()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html), which documents the format codes.

```
as.Date("01/08/15", format = "%m/%d/%y")
## [1] "2015-01-08"
```

Comment: It would be very inconvenient if this returned an error every time there is a typo in the input vector.